AWS glue "split dataset by fields" function
I'm trying to split data from a .csv file and import it in two different tables in PostgreSQL.
I'm using visual glue's "split dataset by fields" function, but after configuring both outputs I try to connect it to a database/catalog but encounter the error:
"Parent node Split Dataset By Fields outputs a collection, but node AWS Glue Data Catalog does not accept a collection"
After searching online, I learned that it should be first connected to a change schema, but when I add it I get the same problem.
I'm new to glue and starting to doubt this tool, since such basic steps are difficult to navigate (used to work with visual studio which is much more intuitive).
I'm also wondering why I can't find a lot of answers online about these problems. Am I here totally on the wrong path? (e.g. glue visual is useless and I have to do it all via coding and pyspark).
